# How to validate the randomness of ECDSA signature generated using HSM?

Tags: random, cryptography, signature, ecdsa, hsm

I need to programmatically (using Python) validate whether the signature generated by using HSM RnG is actually random.

Didn't found much content online, hence any help would be appreciated !!

How do I validate the randomness of ECDSA signature generated using HSM?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Programming questions are off-topic here and even in this form it is also will be closed and downvoted in SO. Therefore I did not ask for migration.

Comment: This is not something you can verify by examining the outputs (unless it's spectacularly broken).  You need a model for how the device works internally.  If you don't trust the HSM _a priori_, looking at the outputs is no way to give you confidence in it.

Answer (score 1):

As Squeamish indicated in the comments, there is not really any way of making sure that the outcome of a random number generator is really random. For instance, it could just be the output of Pi at one particular location. Generally, you'll have to trust the FIPS or Common Criteria certification of the platform, but note that neither one is airtight.

Furthermore, you can also rely on the fact that HSM companies want to make money. One way certain to lose (all) marketshare is to show that you cannot be trusted. Multiple companies, including RSA Labs, already found this out to their detriment. If you don't fully trust a HSM company, then don't buy anything off of them; but note that there is no such thing as *perfect security* in a practical sense.

---

It may be possible to do some simple experiments. If you ask for signature generation using the same data then you should never get the same signature (r and s values for ECDSA). This shows that the output of the RNG at least doesn't repeat. Testing this - once - with several connections / sessions might be a good idea.

You could also verify and then concatenate all the resulting x values (used for the final comparison) and then run a randomness test (such as the diehard suite) over it.

---

Finally, if you don't trust the entropy source of the HSM's RNG, note that you can add additional seeds to a HSM. Please check the documentation of your HSM how it reacts to adding / mixing seeds.

Comment: This is, rightfully, a [crypto.se] answer, not an [so] answer. I think this question should have stayed on [crypto.se]. The asker wanted an SO answer, but the fact that there is no SO answer is a Crypto answer.

Answer (score -1):

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests) gives an overview of methods for checking the randomness of some given data:

> There are many practical measures of randomness for a binary sequence.
>   These include measures based on statistical tests, transforms, and
>   complexity or a mixture of these. A well-known and widely-used
>   collection of tests was the Diehard Battery of Tests, introduced by
>   Marsaglia; this was extended to the TestU01 suite by L'Ecuyer and
>   Simard. The use of Hadamard transform to measure randomness was
>   proposed by S. Kak and developed further by Phillips, Yuen, Hopkins,
>   Beth and Dai, Mund, and Marsaglia and Zaman.

A standardized test suite is defined in the [NIST Special Publication 800-22](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-22/rev-1a/final).

Also check out [this discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83254/how-to-check-randomness-of-random-number-generators).

Comment: This is measuring randomness in a different sense. It's a very complex topic, but basically these are ways to estimate the information theoretic complexity of certain kinds of data, or the entropy level of an entropy source. It doesn't apply to data that has inherent structure such as an ECDSA signature: it would misreport the deep structure as randomness because it wouldn't recognize that structure.